# Why does the add() method of a Linkedlist return true in Java?

Tags: java, api

Why does the `add` method of a Linkedlist return true in Java?

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add(E)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add%28E%29)

Why not just make it a void method? I know it says "per the general contract of Collection.add", but why doesn't this contract/interface make `add` a void method?

Comment: `public void add(int index, E element)` - I don't see a return type there.

Comment: The other `add` method with a slightly different signature. Also, why do the signatures differ between these two overloaded functions?

Comment: @DavidFaux because one is also implemented by `Set`s, and one is specific to `List`s.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is to allow referencing to LinkedList instances as List or Collection.

```
boolean addSomething(Collection c) {
    return c.add(null); // expects collection, with add returning boolean
}


void hackList(LinkedList list) {
    addSomething(list); // list is a Collection, OK to pass
}
```

LinkedList **[is a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a)** List and Collection.

---

As for why a *Collection* would need to return boolean, this looks clearly explained in [respective javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29):

> ...Ensures that this collection contains the specified element (optional operation). Returns `true` if this collection changed as a result of the call. (Returns `false` if this collection does not permit duplicates and already contains the specified element.)...

Comment: Ah, `add` must return true to indicate that the element was successfully added (which collections must do). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the excellent answer gnat gave, it can be useful to know that you just tried to add `null` to a list, and therefore did not change it.  While you could check for this separately, it's kinda nice to be able to say

```
if (myList.add(foo)) { doSomething(); }
```

or perhaps

```
while (myList.add(buffer.readLine()));
```